# how to focus gallery to particular postion in android?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I want display images in gallery view it want to focus to paticular image using its position in android

```
  SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new  SimpleAdapter(ShowingGalleryActivity.this,arrList1, R.layout.showinggalleryview, new String[]{"image","company"},
                    new int[]{R.id.showinggalleryview_goggle_iv,R.id.showinggalleryview_companyname_tv}
                    );
            mGallery.setDescendantFocusability(position);
            mGallery.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the setselection(position) method in the Gallery. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading the documentation?

```
public void setSelection (int position)

Since: API Level 1
Sets the currently selected item. To support accessibility subclasses that override this method must invoke the overriden super method first.
Parameters

position    Index (starting at 0) of the data item to be selected.
```